# Define pas for pas yisroel

Tags: halacha, bread, pat-yisrael

There is the whole discussion of pas with regard to whether it needs to be baked by a Jew... [Yoreh deah siman 112](http://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Yoreh_De'ah.112).

How do we define bread? I know it must contain one of the 5 grains(sif aleph). Does it have to be bread like (soft)? What about granola, which is a grain (oats but is definitely not a "bread"? What about pasta (being that no matter how much you eat you would never make a hamotzei?

Comment: granola if not baked would not be considered bread as the bracha on raw grains would either be shehakol or haadama

Answer (score 3):

To be bread it must have *toar lechem*, "the appearance of bread". So noodles are definitely out, as are cooked grains, which do not even necessarily require *bishul yisrael* (to be cooked by a Jew), but batter-based cakes etc. are in. Beyond that things get hard to pin down, and I have not seen any responsa on the subject. Rav Yitzchok Berkovits says they showed Rav Shlomo Zalman Cheerios, and he said, "אה, קליינע בייגעלאך" - literally, "Small baigels!" but in Israeli parlance, "Small pretzels!" He held that Cheerios have the appearance of bread and would therefore not be pas yisrael. Similarly, I believe I saw a chart from the Star-K which said that if one eats Cheerios to satiety one would be Biblically obligated to say birkat hamazon. However, the Lakewood minhag seems to be to treat Cheerios as a noodle and not require them to be pas yisrael, though I have seen no source for this. I asked Rav Gedaliah Anemer if bran flakes had *toar lechem* and would therefore be forbidden to eat during the 10 Days of Repentence (OC 603:1) and he replied he didn't think so.

The concept of *toar lechem*, "the appearance of bread," comes from OC 168:10, where the Shulchan Aruch approximately says that if you crumble your matzah, wet it and make it into a matzah ball, it loses its "hamotzi" and becomes a "mezonot". Rav Alexander Mandelbaum in *V'Zot haBracha* mentions the the gemara says grains which are *ma'aseh kedeira* ("cooked in a pot") are always mezonot, not hamotzi (Brachot 37a). He quotes several authorities who thought noodles did have *toar lechem*, but Rav Akiva Eiger rejects them and infers that the Rambam agrees with him: even though they are made from dough, since they are not baked, they are not bread-like, and so is the conclusion of the Mishna Brura.

Rav Mandelbaum quotes Rav Mordechai Eliyahu that pancakes and melawach have *toar lechem*. He says breakfast cereals consisting of various baked shapes of some thickness - he mentions Grape Nuts and several Israeli brands - have *toar lechem* according to Rav Shlomo Zalman and Rav Elyashiv, however Rav Scheinberg disagreed. Rav Shlomo Zalman agreed that bran flakes do not have *toar lechem*, but Rav Elyashiv held they did.

I do not know of any source that links YD 112 to OC 168; I think it's taken as self-evident, given that YD 113:1 states that any food which is not eaten raw and which is "suitable for a king's table" is forbidden if cooked by a non-Jew.

Comment: +1. "Rav Yitzchok Berkovits says" -- is this in writing somewhere?

Comment: I always thought the "cheerios = bagels" thing was a joke, but this would actually be sensible.

Comment: @msh210 no, unfortunately not. That is why I was happy to find that R'Mandelbaum backs up my oral tradition for what R'Shlomo Zalman held.

Comment: I find this answer very confusing. 1. "Cheerios have the appearance of bread and would therefore not be pas yisrael" - don't you mean that if they are bread, they **would** be *pas*? 2. When you say that it's self-evident that YD 112 is connected to OC 168, what does this have to do with being suitable for a king's table?

Comment: @Matt I think he means they have the appearance of bread and would therefore be prohibited as pas akum since cheerios are made by akum

Answer (score 0):

Guidelines for the definition of bread for the purposes of this halakha can be found at [Halachipedia, here](http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Pas_akum#What_Breads_and_Foods_are_Included).

To summarize:

- Any **baked** food item made **primarily** from any one or more of the five grains. A good test is whether or not it one would ever recite a bracha of Hamotzi over it, either because it is literally bread or even only if Hamotzi is made when eaten as a meal. (Taz to YD 112:6, Tosfos Beitza 16b)

  - There is an exception to the rule of baked grain foods: anything which does not "look like bread" never requires Hamotzi (Rama O.C. 168:13, Shulchan Aruch O.C. 168:15, Mishnah Berurah ibid. 168:3) and therefore is not bread for the purpose of this halakha as well (Shakh YD 112:18 quoting Toras Chatas 75:12). Therefore, pasta and most breakfast cereals are accordingly considered not bread (see [here](http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Pas_akum#cite_note-57) and [here](https://www.chazaq.org/?section=articles&categoryId=52&articleId=862#_ftnref65)).
  - Another possible exception is where food was baked from a pour-able batter, as opposed to solid dough. This is subject to dispute (Chelkas Binyamin 112:64)
- According to some, fried or deep-fried foods made primarily from one of the five grains (such as donuts) are also considered bread for this purpose. (Implied by Tosafos Pesachim 37b, but Aruch Hashulchan Y.D. 112:31 based upon Tashbetz 3:11 and Rivash 28 holds that these foods are not bread)
- Foods made from dough that were cooked in water instead of baked are not considered "bread" for this purpose. However, [bagels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bagel) are not made edible by the boiling done before baking, and so bagels are considered to be bread. (Aruch Hashulchan Y.D. 112:31)

Answer (score 0):

The star k certifies [Israeli cheerios as pas yisrael](https://www.star-k.org/resource/list/UK0XE63K/Cereals_and_their_Brachos), seemingly someone there holds it should/must be.

Comment: And yet, in their Aseres Yemei Teshuva list they say cheerios do not need to be pas yisroel. Weird. https://baltimorejewishlife.com/pdfs/pas-yisroel-guide.pdf